# How can we cycle elements of a array when here, the bind method is set to a preset value?

Tags: javascript, bind

I understand that `bind()` takes a argument from another function creates a copy with a preset argument value and assigns that to another function, but in this example I simply don’t understand how we can take the `limit` argument and the function still works, when `limit` is preset to **20**, where and how are the array elements that we are cycling through passed in and compared when we store them in `minAgeForJapan`? I hope I was as clear as I could be, thx.

````
let years = [1990, 1965, 1947, 2005, 2001];

function arrCalc(arr,funcPassedIn) {
    let result =  [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push(funcPassedIn(arr[i]));
    }
    return result;
};

function calcAgeFunc(arrayIndex) {
    return 2020 - arrayIndex;
};
let agesCalculated = arrCalc(years, calcAgeFunc);
console.log(agesCalculated);//[30, 55, 83, 15, 19];

function isFullAge (limit, arrayIndex) {
    return arrayIndex >= limit;
}

let minAgeForJapan = arrCalc(agesCalculated, isFullAge.bind(this, 20));//we set the min age to 20 
console.log(minAgeForJapan);//[true, true, true, false, false]```
````

Comment: `isFullAge` is a function that accepts two arguments. `isFullAge.bind(this, 20)` returns a function that accepts one argument. It essentially becomes `function isFullAge2(arrayIndex) { return arrayIndex >= 20; }`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @FelixKling, thank you very much, that does make sense